# how to fetch the records from the table for last 24 hrs

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find records in a (Oracle SQL) table using the creation date field where records are older than 24hrs and set some status once. To find records using a operators like > but if anyone can suggest quick SQL where clause statement to find records older than 24hrs that would be nice.

Comment: ..`where creation_date < SYSDATE - 1` should be fine for "records older than 24hrs " . Your question title says the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query to fetch the same

SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   record_date >= SYSDATE - 1

Answer (score 0):

Get records younger than 24 hours:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE record_date > SYSDATE - 1
```

Get records older than 24 hours:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE record_date < SYSDATE - 1
```

Get records from today:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE record_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

Get records from before today:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE record_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE
```

Set records older than 24 h to old status:

```
UPDATE table SET status = 'old'
WHERE record_date < SYSYDATE - 1
```

Remember that adding/subtracting numbers to dates in oracle adds or removes that number of days or part days.

```
01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 + 1.5 = 02-Jan-1970 00:06:00
```

Let's add 3 days 17 hours and 26 minutes:

```
01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 + 3 + (17/24) + (26/60/24)
```